# Can't get output for GLM regression of income (categorical) on binomial dummy variable in R

Tags: r, regression, glm, categorical-data

I'm very new both to R and econometrics in general, but I couldn't seem to find a helpful answer anywhere else.

I'm trying to see whether a certain self-reported factor helps explain income in Asian-Americans more than simply education.  I've created a dummy variable for that factor:

```
american.typical <- as.numeric(PewData$q24 == "Typical American")
```

Income is split into nine categories plus a non-response category, and education is split into seven categories plus a non-response category.

I originally created a dummy variable for each income category, but then I discovered the GLM function and thought that it might be unnecessary.  However, all commands that I try in this fashion:

```
glm(PewData$income ~ PewData$educ)
glm(PewData$income ~ american.typical)
```

return this:

```
Error in glm.fit(x = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,  : 
  NA/NaN/Inf in 'y'
In addition: Warning messages:
1: In Ops.factor(y, mu) : ‘-’ not meaningful for factors
2: In Ops.factor(eta, offset) : ‘-’ not meaningful for factors
3: In Ops.factor(y, mu) : ‘-’ not meaningful for factors
```

Further, any plot that I try to make is completely unhelpful, leading me to believe that I'm going astray in my approach rather than execution.

Any advice is greatly appreciated.

EDIT: I've also tried logistic regression via [this method](https://www.r-bloggers.com/how-to-perform-a-logistic-regression-in-r/), but to no avail.

Comment: @MarcoSandri: `Typical American (1240), Very different from typical American (1964), Don't Know/Refused (307)`

Comment: @MarcoSandri, 
`american.typical
   0 (2271)   1 (1240)`
I'm not quite sure what these values represent.  Is it that the treatment group receives an additional 1,240 units of income?

Comment: Logistic regression is suitable for a binary (two-level) response variable. Other GLMs exist for other response types. You seem to have multiple ordered categories (income levels) as the response, so you will need to do an ordinal logistic regression. You should search for tutorials on that, there are many good ones.